# javascript / html auto refresh button

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to build a webpage button  which if clicked reloads the webpage every x seconds (i.e. 5 seconds = 5000 ms). The Problem is that my function gets executed once after 5 seconds, but wont continue to auto refresh after the button was clicked. It always waits for the next button click. 
In theory I know that after the click my function has to be called every x seconds, but I simply don't know how to implement this.
This is how far i got:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id = "btn-reload">Automatischer Reload der Seite</button>
    <script>
        const btnReload = document.getElementById("btn-reload");

        btnReload.addEventListener("click", function(){
            setInterval(function(){
            location.reload()}, 5000);

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, you might want to set something in the localStorage that auto-refresh is enabled, and validate that when you are loading your webpage, and in case it is enabled, start the interval

Comment: I think you are tying to do something like real-time notifications, `setInterval` is the worst solutions for this, it may cause many problems. read more about `socket` or `signal-R` .

Comment: location.reload will reload the page and set all html control with its initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you refreshing page all state is cleared so also interval not exist. To make it work you need something which will save the state between refresh for example local storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL as your flag if auto refresh is enabled.

> Example your-url.com?autorefresh=true

on window load check this flag is set or not to run your auto refresh feature